# .NET (core) standard library for representing custom queries from front end

Tags: json, api, dynamic, .net-core, specifications

So, I'm in the position, for probably the fourth or fifth time, of writing a .net core backend of a dynamic query handler.

Basically, an API that takes a query from the front end (a REACT app, but that's not my concern) and converts it to a SQL query (using EF Core). I'm wondering if there's an actual "standard" way/library for implementing this.  This is SUCH a common requirement,I really want to avoid inventing the wheel yet again.

Requirements are pretty standard: result field list, sorting list, filter list. All of it interpreted and converted to a db query, with the results returned to the caller.  Also there's a requirement to optionally save the query/field set, but that's not a big addition.

I haven't found anything after a few hours of searching, but I feel like there has to be something.  I'm thinking some kind of JSON representation of the query comes in, is parsed, and interpreted. I feel like there must be some library that does this?

Yes I can write this, but at this point it just feels wrong.

Comment: You're probably looking for ODATA or GraphQL

Comment: Right. I gave JSON:API as an example in my answer. @StevenB. examples are relevant too.

Answer (score 0):

It exists, but you'll always need to agree with the front end developper on how the requests and responses are formatted.

For example you can both agree to use the [{JSON:API}](https://jsonapi.org) specifications. Then on the back end side you'll be able to use a library such as [JsonApiDotNetCore](https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore):

> The ultimate goal of this library is to eliminate as much boilerplate
>   as possible by offering out-of-the-box features such as sorting,
>   filtering and pagination. You just need to focus on defining the
>   resources and implementing your custom business logic.

Disclaimer: I haven't used that library. I'm just explaining you how to achieve that you want. The main information of my answer is to agree on a well-known format/specification for the API, so that both developers will find an implementation for the frond and back ends.